# how to remove duplicates in js "reactnative picker"

Tags: react-native, picker

Please find the below data. Here is I need only Id:1 data. Some Id's have no values and some Id's have another values.

Actual data:

```
data[
 {Id: 1, Specialization: "General", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/doctor.png", Description: "General", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 2, Specialization: "Cardiology", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/heartbeat.png", Description: "Hart Related", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 3, Specialization: "Gynaecology", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/nephrology.png", Description: "Gynaecology", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 4, Specialization: "Orthopedic", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/mental.png", Description: "Bones", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 4, Specialization: "Orthopedic", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/mental.png", Description: "Bones", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 1, Specialization: "General", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/doctor.png", Description: "General", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 3, Specialization: "Gynaecology", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/nephrology.png", Description: "Gynaecology", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 3, Specialization: "Gynaecology", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/nephrology.png", Description: "Gynaecology", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 2, Specialization: "Cardiology", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/heartbeat.png", Description: "Hart Related", IsActive: true, …}
]
```

i need like this

```
data[
{Id: 1, Specialization: "General", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/doctor.png", Description: "General", IsActive: true, …}
{Id: 2, Specialization: "Cardiology", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/heartbeat.png", Description: "Hart Related", IsActive: true, …}
{Id: 3, Specialization: "Gynaecology", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/nephrology.png", Description: "Gynaecology", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 4, Specialization: "Orthopedic", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/mental.png", Description: "Bones", IsActive: true, …}
]
```

Comment: what you try for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```js
const data = [
 {Id: 1, Specialization: "General", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/doctor.png", Description: "General", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 2, Specialization: "Cardiology", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/heartbeat.png", Description: "Hart Related", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 3, Specialization: "Gynaecology", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/nephrology.png", Description: "Gynaecology", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 4, Specialization: "Orthopedic", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/mental.png", Description: "Bones", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 4, Specialization: "Orthopedic", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/mental.png", Description: "Bones", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 1, Specialization: "General", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/doctor.png", Description: "General", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 3, Specialization: "Gynaecology", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/nephrology.png", Description: "Gynaecology", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 3, Specialization: "Gynaecology", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/nephrology.png", Description: "Gynaecology", IsActive: true, …}
 {Id: 2, Specialization: "Cardiology", ImageUrl: "http://122.175.55.55:8080/storage/loadfile/specialization/heartbeat.png", Description: "Hart Related", IsActive: true, …}
]

const getUniqueData = (data) => {
  const indexes = [];
  const uniqueData = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(indexes.contains(data[i].id)){
      continue; 
    } else {
      indexes.push(data[i].id);
      uniqueData.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  
  return uniqueData;
}

const uniqueData = getUniqueData(data);
```

This is of course a primitive solution. You can try javascipt Sets or lodash library for cases like these.